# Expression for Laplace-Beltrami on sphere?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Is there a good expression for the Laplace-Beltrami on a function $u$ on a sphere or a circle of radius $R>0$ in terms of the Laplacian on ambient space?

There is a formula on Wikipedia for the unit sphere:
$$\Delta_{S^{n-1}}f(x) = \Delta f(x/|x|).$$
How about sphere of radius $R$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbf{R}}$To confirm jena's answer: Let $S^{n-1}$ denote the sphere $\sum_{i} x_{i}^{2} = 1$, *regarded merely as a smooth manifold*. For $R > 0$, let $g(R)$ denote the round metric of radius $R$ on $S^{n-1}$.

The mapping $i_{R}:\bigl(S^{n-1}, g(R)\bigr) \to \R^{n}$ defined by $i_{R}(x) = Rx$ is an isometric embedding, so the image $i_{R}(S^{n-1})$ may be identified with $S^{n-1}(R)$, the sphere of radius $R$ in $\R^{n}$.

Using the argument outlined on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator#Examples), if $f:S^{n-1}(R) \to \R$ is twice continuously-differentiable, define $\hat{f}:\R^{n}\setminus\{0\} \to \R$ by $\hat{f}(x) = f\bigl(Rx/\|x\|\bigr)$, i.e., extend $f$ to be constant along rays through the origin. The induced function $\tilde{f}:S^{n-1} \to \R$ satisfies
$$
\tilde{f}(x/R) = \hat{f}(x) = f(x)\quad\text{for $x$ in $S^{n-1}(R)$.}
%\tilde{f}(x/\|x\|) = \hat{f}(x) = f(Rx/\|x\|)\quad\text{for $x$ in $\R^{n}$.}
$$
In other words, $f$ and $\tilde{f}$ are *identical as functions* on the smooth manifold $S^{n-1}$, and each is obtained by restricting $\hat{f}$ to the appropriate sphere in $\R^{n}$.

Since $g(R) = R^{2} g(1)$ and the trace of the Hessian depends inversely on the metric components,
$$
\frac{1}{R^{2}}\, \Delta_{S^{n-1}(R)} f
  = \Delta_{S^{n-1}(1)} \tilde{f}
  = \Delta \hat{f}
$$
by the [formula for the Laplacian in spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#N_dimensions).

Comment: Thank you very much. So we just multiply by $R^2$.

Comment: I don't really understand the last three lines and asked a question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2542113/chain-rule-for-laplace-beltrami-operator-on-spheres

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to find in the internet.  By googling Laplace operator in spherical coordinates,
you will find an expression (in the usual form, with three terms) involving partial derivatives with respect to $r$ and the two angle coordinates.  Simply remove the term involving differentiation with respect to $r$  (the first one in the usual formatting) and this is what you require.  (I would type it here but it is rather complicated).  (In the remaining terms, set $r=1$  or $r=R$ for the case of a sphere with radius $R$). The same procedure works for the cicle of radius $R$.

Comment: I hope that I understood your query correctly.

Comment: I don't think this is my query.. see the updated post.

Comment: @riem: Even considering your updates, jena's answer looks (to me) that it does address your question (aside from the lack of an actual formula); perhaps this means I've also misunderstood what you're asking. Could you please explain why jena's post doesn't answer your query?

Comment: @user86418 Well for a start I found the answer a bit confusing regarding which formulae to use. Not my downvote btw. I have not seen any formula relating the Laplace-Beltrami to ambient Laplacian (except for $R=1$) in any coordinates. That said I am not comfortable in this area so that's why I preferred a concrete answer.