# "chain rule" for Laplace-Beltrami operator on spheres

Tags: geometry, analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $\Delta_{S^{n-1}(R)}$ be the Laplace-Beltrami operator $\Delta_{S^{n-1}(R)}$ on the $(n-1)$-dimensional sphere $S^{n-1}(R)\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ with radius $R$.

Define $i_R\colon S^{n-1}(1)\to S^{n-1}(R)$ by $i_R(\xi):=R\xi$. I think for smooth $f\colon{S^{n-1}(R)}\to \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
\Delta_{S^{n-1}(1)}(i_R^* f)(\xi)=R^2 \Delta_{S^{n-1}(R)}f(x)|_{x=R\xi},\tag{$\star$}
$$
where $(i_R^* f)(\xi):=f(i_R(\xi))$ is the pullback of $f$ by $i_R$.

This seems to be a natural extension of the chain rule in the one dimensional case $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}(ax)|_{x=x^*}=a^2f''(ax^*)$, but it does not seem to be consistent with

> [Expression for Laplace-Beltrami on sphere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736401/expression-for-laplace-beltrami-on-sphere)

**Question:** **Is ($\star$) correct?**